# how to get rid of Compute Launch Button Tooltip error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

This error started coming this morning and it's driving me crazy
It didn't actually start suddenly, I had imported a few projects which did not compile, after which this started happening, but I cannot remember exactly all the things that I did to make it start

When I bring the cursor above the green compile button, an error message appears that says `Compute Launch Button Tooltip error` and some vague description which just says that there was an error in evaluating the Launch button tooltip. the error message is blocking so I cannot click anywhere on eclipse interface until I click OK on the message. Nothing else happens, but I'm not able to compile and run anything either, since this error appears as soon as the cursor hovers over the green run button (or the debug as well, I think). If I right click on the project icon in the project explorer, bringing the cursor over the run option does not bring up the submenu either

--- EDIT ---
[image]

---

If I restart the computer and do it again, it works. However if I close Eclipse again and restart it (Eclipse that is), the problem appears again, until I restart the computer.

How do I stop this error from happening?

--- EDIT 2 ---

I moved the .launch files as pointed out in the answer to a backup location. I hadn't included this information before, but when I start up Eclipse this message appears as well, when Eclipse is loading and the splash screen is visible:
[image]

Even after I moved the .launch files to a backup location, after eclipse starts up, I still get the `Compute Launch Button Tooltip error` when I hover over the green compile button. What can I do now?

--- EDIT 3 ---
After the above messages, if i close eclipse IDE and then start it up again (without restarting my computer), I get the following error:
[image]
After this the IDE doesn't even start up. The log file it mentions is too big and I don't know what to look for inside it.

--- EDIT 4 ---
Further experiment

I deleted the .metadata folder and restarted Eclipse in the same workspace. Now eclipse seems to treat it as a new workspace and does not even show the project folder that is there, in it's project tree. So I go to file > import  > import existing project into workspace, and import the same project folder that is in the workspace back using Eclipse, and do not check the Copy project to workspace check box. This seems to make it work, but if I close Eclipse, and try to start it again, then I get the error message in EDIT 3nd Eclipse does not start up. What could have gone wrong here?

Comment: What happens again? Do you see an error message?

Comment: yes it happens again, until I restart my computer

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any information about the error. You only say "it happens, it happens, it happens." **What** happens? Do you get an error message? Does Eclipse crash?

Comment: oh Sorry I just noticed that I forgot to post the screenshot, and I'm not at that computer anymore, I'll try to describe it instead

Comment: The interesting part of the log file is usually at the bottom. Each entry in it has a time stamp, try to find one around the time when you saw the error message.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like you have a corrupt `.launch` config file somewhere in your workspace.

You can find these files in `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/` or in your projects if you select "Shared File" in the last tab of the launch config.

It should be enough to delete (or move) all the "*.launch" files to make Eclipse work again.

Comment: making a completely new workspace and importing my project in it seems to work though. Is it possible to fix my old workspace.

Comment: Not likely. Eclipse sometimes corrupts important files in `.metadata`. If that happens, there is no surefire way to fix everything again.

Comment: if I keep an hourly backup of the `.metadata` folder, can just reverting to a backup version fix this, if something like this happens again? Or does it corrupt files in some other locations as well?

Comment: Please see the latest EDIT 4. Thank you.

Comment: Eclipse usually doesn't use files outside of the workspace. It's disturbing that the error returns after you delete the `.metadata` folder and restart. You will have to look into the log file and try to understand what's in there.

Comment: Any solution for this problem. I don't find any solution till now.

Comment: @sumitkumarpradhan Please check the .log file and ask a new question with the last error from the log in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java
```

Comment: What does this command do and why it solves the problem? some people may not know or understand.

Comment: @LucianoBrum it looks like 5 years ago, under Linux, re-installation of the java time zone data package solved the problem. Other posts suggest that the Eclipse bug that caused the problem was somehow related to time zones.

Answer (score 1):

Added "`-Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU`" to eclipse.ini file and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in `eclipse.ini`. This might sort out the problem.

```
-Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU
```